# Can a subdomain delete a domain cookie?

Tags: http, cookies

Suppose I have a cookie that is set for .domain.com, and my subdomain is sub.domain.com. Can I delete cookies that are set for the main domain? I know it is possible to read them, but is it possible to delete these cookies, or overwrite their values?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, a subdomain can set/expire a cookie for the main domain, but the main domain cannot set/expire a cookie for a subdomain. See RFC 6265 Sections [5.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3), [5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3) (see point #6), and [8.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-8.6). Section 8.6 in particular describes how a subdomain can set a cookie for the main domain and have it affect a sibling subdomain.